# Coefficient growth upper bound of a recurrence relation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, recurrences, difference-equations

Consider the recurrence relation one can obtain from the radial Schrödinger equation for the hydrogen atom, where $\psi(r)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nr^n$:

$$(n+3)(n+2)a_{n+2}+2a_{n+1}=2|E|a_n, n\geq0$$

Subject to $a_{n} = 0$ for $n \lt 0$, and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sup |a_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}=0$. The solutions to this equation are well-known (these are just the hydrogen s-orbitals), so I am not interested in solving it, or obtaining the quantised energies. What I am interested in is how one can connect the rate of decay of the absolute value of the coefficients to the form of the recurrence relation, when one *cannot* provide a nice closed-form solution of the above equation.

Given that the above is an eigenvalue equation, it is natural to assume a solution of the form (of course, it is a separate question entirely how generally applicable this assumption is - it certainly does not hold when $a_n=0$, but it does hold for the solutions to the hydrogen atom):

$$a_{n+1} = -f(n+1)a_n$$

for some $f(n)$ that is strictly positive for all $n>0$. It is clear from the form of the recurrence relation that we want $f(n)\sim O(\frac{1}{n})$, so for large enough $n$, we can say that $f(n)$ will be a strictly decreasing function. However, when one studies the actual solutions to the above recurrence relation, it seems that $f(n+1) < f(n)$ for all $n>0$, not just at the large $n$ limit. Therefore, I am wondering if one can relate the form and/or the coefficients in the above recurrence relation to some sort of upper bound of coefficient decay that is true for **all** $n$, not just at the asymptotic limit. Or put another way: how can we enforce quantisation with a limited number of terms without necessarily having a closed-form solution that we can confidently say decays to 0 at infinite $n$.

I also suspect the answer to this would be related to putting an upper bound to the value of $2|E|$, which of course happens to be 1. I imagine there must be a deeper reason why $2|E|$ cannot be e.g. $1000$, which would give coefficients with oscillatory behaviour that will ultimately not converge to the desired limits.

I realise there is a lot to this question, but any insight would be appreciated, as it seems that recurrence relations are not as well-studied as some other branches of mathematics.

Comment: Can you clarify what you’re asking? Your question seems interesting but I’m at a loss about what you actually want to know, why what you say is well-known is well-known, and why $2|E|$ is “of course” 1 (and I say this as someone who had a reasonably good understanding of the QM hydrogen atom model at one point, although it’s not something I looked at recently).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the reason I say the solutions are "well-known" is because one can solve this equation using means other than this recurrence relation, but I am not interested in such methods and I want to know what knowledge can be extracted purely from that relation alone without actually solving it. More specifically, it seems that one should be able to prove that the absolute value of the ratio of two consecutive terms (i.e. $f(n+1)$) is always a strictly decreasing function of $n$, not only at large values, but at all values. But how one would prove that is not obvious to me.

Comment: Okay, it’s still much too vague for me to think about, but good luck. If you could add links that explain the background material you’re referencing, you’ll have a better chance of getting some useful suggestions IMO.